# Socket Server via Singleton with parameters from properties file

Tags: java, sockets

I am going to run Socket Server via Singleton Pattern because I have multiple threads, and every time I call it, I want to use the same socket server. This is `SocketSingleton.java` class :

```
public class SocketSingleton {

    private static ServerSocket serverSocket = null;

    private SocketSingleton() {}

    public static synchronized ServerSocket getServerSocket() throws IOException {
        PropertiesKey prop = new PropertiesKey();
        if (serverSocket == null) {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(prop.getSocketPort());
        }
        return serverSocket;
    }
}
```

But I've noticed that I should get my few values from `configuration.properties` like `SOCKET_PORT=2203`

I can get the values from configuration with the code bellow

```
public class PropertiesAlgorithmImpl implements PropertiesAlgorithm {
    private static Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
    static {
        try {
            String propertiesDirectory = "src/main/resources/configuration.properties";
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(propertiesDirectory);
            if (in == null) {
                System.out.println("Sorry, unable to find " +  propertiesDirectory);
            }
            defaultProps.load(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getValuesFromProperties(String key) {
        if (defaultProps.getProperty(key) != null) {
            return defaultProps.getProperty(key);
        }
        return "Sorry, unable to find " + key ;
    }

}
```

This is an enum of Socket Port. 
`public enum CONFIG { SOCKET_PORT}`

```
public class PropertiesKey {

    private PropertiesAlgorithm propertiesAlgorithm;

    public int getSocketPort(){
        propertiesAlgorithm = new PropertiesAlgorithmImpl(); 
        return Integer.parseInt(propertiesAlgorithm.getValuesFromProperties(CONFIG.SOCKET_PORT.name()));
    }
```

In the SocketSingleton class, I am calling socket port like this:

`serverSocket = new ServerSocket(prop.getSocketPort());`

What is the possible reason that I can't get the socket port parameters from `configuration.properties`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the class bellow with input stream and it worked:

```
public class PropertiesAlgorithmImpl implements PropertiesAlgorithm {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesAlgorithmImpl.class);
private static Properties defaultProps = new Properties();

static {
    String propertiesDirectory = "config.properties";
    try (InputStream input = PropertiesAlgorithmImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesDirectory)) {
        if (input == null) {
            logger.info("Sorry, unable to find " +  propertiesDirectory);
        }
        defaultProps.load(input);
        input.close();
    } catch (Exception e) { logger.info(String.valueOf(e.getStackTrace())); }
}

public String getValuesFromProperties(String key) {
    if (defaultProps.getProperty(key) != null) {
        return defaultProps.getProperty(key);
    }
        logger.info("Sorry, unable to find " + key);
        return "Sorry, unable to find " + key ;
}
```